# Why do we cast constant literals

Tags: c

I am wondering why do we cast constants when using `#define` preprocessor?

For example:

```
#define WIDTH 128
```

Would it be equal to `-128` in an 8bit platform?

What if I change it like this:

```
#define WIDTH 128U
```

What would it be equal to, on 8bit platform?

What is the default **sizeof** a constant integers like the above? Do its length/type depends on the platform architecture, or it depends on the type of the literal value they hold?

Sorry about my bad English.

Comment: `int` is guaranteed to be at least 16 bit.

Comment: An unadorned source code integer in the range of `int` has type `int`.

Comment: The title doesn't seem to match the question, there are no casts in this code

Comment: Please see this manual at page 26 [link](https://www.ccsinfo.com/downloads/ccs_c_manual.pdf)

You can see that `int` is 8 bits long for this compiler. Although it doesn't conform C99 standart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving C99 chapters because I don't have the C11 document at hand.

---

**ISO/IEC 9899:1999, 6.4.4.1 Integer constants**

> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented.

For decimal constants without suffix:

- `int`
- `long int`
- `long long int`

For decimal constants with `u` or `U` suffix:

- `unsigned int`
- `unsigned long int`
- `unsigned long long int`

---

**ISO/IEC 9899:1999, 5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types**

The width of integer types is implementation-defined, as is the binary representation.

`INT_MAX` -- the largest value an `int` can take -- is *guaranteed* to be *at least* `+32767`.

`UINT_MAX` -- the largest value an `unsigned int` can take -- is *guaranteed* to be *at least* `65535`.

---

**ISO/IEC 9899:1999, 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions**

If you *compare* an `int` with an `unsigned int`, the `int` will be implicitly converted to `unsigned int` for the comparison. Similar for the `short` / `long` / `long long` types. As @chqrlie pointed out, this can be a problem; your compiler should give you a warning if this happens (you *are* always compiling with `-Wall -Wextra` / `/W3` enabled, aren't you?).

---

**Summary**

Your constants will fit into an `int` / `unsigned int` even on an 8-bit machine. Assuming they would not, the compiler would use the next largest type for them (instead of casting the value).

As for *why* we do it...

If you, for example, intend to use `WIDTH` for comparisons with the result of `sizeof()`, or the return code of `strlen()`, or anything else that is `unsigned` by nature, you would want `WIDTH` to have the same value domain, i.e. being able to hold all possible values.

That is why you would want `WIDTH` to be `unsigned` as well.

Comment: Good answer, but regarding *you would not want to receive a compiler warning each time*, I don't think the compiler would issue a warning for `sizeof(buffer) > 128`, so this is not a good reason for using a `U` suffix.  Forcing unsigned arithmetic as in the example provided by skyking is more interesting, but still debatable.

Comment: @chqrlie: Indeed. Rephrased the last paragraph to mention value domain only.

Answer (score 4):

Defining `WIDTH` as `128` poses no problems, `int` is at least 16 bit wide on all conforming platforms.

Defining `WIDTH` as `128U` would make it an unsigned integer constant literal.  Since the value fits in an `unsigned int` (mandated to be at least 16 bit wide), it has type `unsigned int`.  `sizeof(WIDTH)` evaluates to `sizeof(unsigned int)`, which is entirely platform specific.

Using this suffix is **not recommended**.  It would have surprising side effects:

```
 if (WIDTH > -1) {
    printf("This will never print\n");
 }
```

Since `WIDTH` expands to `128U`, an `unsigned` constant, the comparison is performed as an unsigned comparison, `-1` is converted to `unsigned` and becomes `UINT_MAX`, a value much larger than `128`.  Don't do this.

If you subsequently store `WIDTH` into a `char` variable, you may have a problem.  It would actually not make a difference whether you define it as `128` or `128U`, you would still have an overflow if the `char` type is 8 bit and signed, leading to undefined behavior.  On most platforms, the value stored would indeed be `-128` but you cannot even rely on that.

More importantly, you should use all the help the compiler can give you by enabling all compiler warnings and making them errors:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror
```

or

```
clang -Weverything -Werror
```

Very few of these warnings are annoying, most of them are very useful and point to silly mistakes, typos and oversights.

Comment: Well... +1 overall, but I disagree on unsigned being "not recommended". Using unsigned integers is perfectly valid. What you should **not** do is *mixing* signed and unsigned in comparisons. That's why modern compilers issue a warning about it.

Comment: @DevSolar: I agree with you, but sadly, modern compilers only warn about signed/unsigned comparison mismatch if explicit instructed to do so.  I always use `-Wall -W -Werror`, but most programmers are unaware if these issues and would probably ignore these warnings anyway, leading to trouble.  This is why I would not recommend the unsigned suffix in this case.

Comment: The suffix `U` makes it exactly `unsigned int` regardless of the sizes of types

Comment: @chqrlie: Anyone not running the compiler in the strictest error checking mode possible is just negligient. Recommending `-Wall -Wextra` *at the very least* beats recommending not to use `unsigned` any time of the day. Especially since you can't really avoid *using* unsigned values anyway (`size_t`).

Comment: @M.M: Actually, no. 6.4.4.1 paragraph 5: "The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented." For `u` / `U` suffix to a decimal constant, the list is `unsigned int` / `unsigned long int` / `unsigned long long int`.

Comment: @DevSolar I just don't understand why compiler makers don't put the default settings to be a bit more strict. So many of them lack warnings for many bad cases by default. Would help the world to fix that.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: The problem here is not so much the compiler manufacturers but that nasty tradition of (a certain breed of) programmers to claim "I know what I am doing", and "it's perfectly *legal* to do this". And then there is that really, really bad word "historical". (The first compilers could not *give* those warnings.) --- But yes, more warnings by default *would* benefit programmers greatly, *especially* that certain breed (that would have to get their act together and either *fixing* those issues or *deliberately* turning those warnings *off*).

Answer (score 2):

First of all `128` is **not** equal to `-128` on a 8-bit platform.

Second this has nothing to do with the preprocessor. What the preprocessor does is to replace `WIDTH` with whatever it's defined as. That is the question is why you write `128` or `128u` in your source.

The suffix `u` is not about type casting, it's about to indicate the type of the literal. In this example `128` is an literal with value 128 of type `int` while `128u` is a literal with value 128 of type `unsigned int`. It's not a problem immediately here, but if you start to use them and end up larger than `32767` you could run into problems. For example:

```
#define WIDTH   256u
#define HEIGHT  192u

unsigned npixels = WIDTH * HEIGHT;
```

it should be noted that the suffices are required to make it portable (what could happen is that the platform only uses 16-bit `int`s and with int the multiplication would overflow which means undefined behavior).

Also note that in newer C standards (but not the antique ones) will extend the literal to become as large as necessary if possible. For example the literal `32768` means a signed integral type with value `32768`, if `int` isn't large enough to hold that signed number then larger types would be used.

The `sizeof` these integers are the same as `sizeof(int)` as the type of the literals are `int` and `unsigned int`. The actual value of `sizeof(int)` could be any positive integer.

Comment: `sizeof(128U)` will actually be computed as `sizeof(unsigned)` since `128U` is of type `unsigned`.     `sizeof` detects the type of its operand.   But, yes, `sizeof int` is generally equal to `sizeof unsigned`.

Comment: @Peter The C standard requires that `sizeof(unsigned)=sizeof(int)`.

Comment: on 16 bit platforms, `sizeof(32768)>sizeof(128)` whereas `sizeof(32768U)==size(128)`.  When passing arguments to `printf`, it is essential to not pass a `long` inadvertently where an `int` is expected.  Compiling with warnings enabled (`gcc -Wall -W -Werror`) will help avoid this kind of error.

Comment: You should always cast arguments to `printf` if not exactly sure about their type

Comment: Sending integer literals to `printf` seems stupid. You have to explicitely type cast it to be sure what type it will take to be portable.

Comment: @Peter 6.2.5p6: "For  each of the signed integer types, there is a corresponding (but different) unsigned integer type (designated with the keyword unsigned)  that uses the same amount of storage (including sign information) and has the same alignment requirements. ", to me that sounds that they should have the same size.